# Getting values from buttons created runtime in c# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I am creating 2 buttons during run-time and I need to do different thing depending upon which button clicked,

following is the code, I have written for click event, however I don't know how do I code where my program understand which button is being clicked.

```
        {
        .
        .
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Location = new Point(x+70,y);
        btn.Height = 15;
        btn.Width = 50;
        Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Name = "button1";
        btn.Click +=btn_Click;
        btn = new Button();
        btn.Location = new Point(x + 140, y);
        btn.Height = 15;
        btn.Width = 50;
        Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Name = "button2";
        btn.Click += btn_Click;
       }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // Understand which of the buttons is clicked!  
    }
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controls all have a `Tag` property that can have any object assigned to it.  You don't even really need to use the `Name` property when creating the buttons programmatically. Here I've used simply strings, but any unique action the button can take can be distilled to its required elements and the things it needs to do that can be put into an object and assigned to the `Tag` property.

```
Button btn = new Button();
Controls.Add(btn);
btn.Tag = "Hello from Button #1";
btn.Click += btn_Click;

btn = new Button();
Controls.Add(btn);
btn.Tag = "Hello from Button #2";
btn.Click += btn_Click;
```

In the event handler you are passed the `sender`, which is a reference to the control that raised the event.  You can then access its `Tag` property with a simple cast :

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Control) { 
        MessageBox.Show(((Control)sender).Tag.ToString()); 
    }
}
```

To show the example that the `Tag` can be anything :

```
Button btn = new Button();
Controls.Add(btn);
btn.Tag = Color.Blue;
btn.Click += btn_Click;

btn = new Button();
Controls.Add(btn);
btn.Tag = Color.Red;
btn.Click += btn_Click;
```

and

```
    if (sender is Control) {
        this.BackColor = (Color)((Control)sender).Tag; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`object sender` is the object which fired the event. In your example the sender is the button clicked. So you can cast sender to `Button` and decide what you want to do.

Comment: I thought so but  am unable to tweak with the sender, can you please elaborate with an example?